# Update date on custom wordpress meta field only if needed

Tags: php, wordpress, function, action, hook

On save_post, I want to add expiring date (now + 30 days) to a post if this meta_key doesn't exist, otherwise do nothing.
I tried with this code in my function.php:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_date' );
  function update_date( $post_id ) { 
  $expire = date( 'm/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime( '+' . '30' . ' days' ) );
  $meta_exist = get_post_meta($post_id, 'expire_date', true);
  if ($meta_exist == ''){
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'expire_date', $expire, true );
  }
}
```

But I noted that this way it update always the date, also if it is already defined.

How to add the date only if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify post is not a revision, I change your code slighty:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_date' );
function update_date( $post_id ) {
  if (!wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
    $expire = date( 'm/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime( '+' . '30' . ' days' ) );
    $meta_exist = get_post_meta($post_id, 'expire_date', true);
    if (!$meta_exist){
      add_post_meta( $post_id, 'expire_date', $expire, true );
    }
  }
}
```